# How to Add Portable Programs to Installed programs in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, portability

how can I add portable program as installed programs in the programs and features page ?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: that is the purpose of portable Programs, that they are not installed and don't add registry entries,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply no. You cannot add. The programs shown in programs and features has their dedicated installer. Portable programs do not have the installer. Most of the time the portable programs are clubbed in zip file. And you can run those programs just double clicking on applications file. No need of installtion.